# Looking for instructions for brick set #135149, silver robot head and black police vest?

Tags: instructions, the-lego-movie

I have part two and part three of the this set and I am pretty sure this set has to come from the "Lego Movie" series. The reason I say is because one of the bags has one or two of the secret police robots in it. Can anyone help identify this set? I can't find any info on any of those sets in that series.

[image]

Comment: Welcome Tyrone! FYI, that set # is just the part number of the plastic bag, not the real set number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at 2 bags from set [70808 - Super Cycle Chase](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=70808-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D). This is the only LEGO Movie set that has [the robo SWAT cop head](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb1083&idColor=95#T=S&C=95&O=%7B%22color%22:95,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D), [the fence](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=2486&idColor=85#T=S&C=85&O=%7B%22color%22:85,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D), [the white 1x2x2 panel](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=87552&idColor=1#T=S&C=1&O=%7B%22color%22:1,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) and [the 1x4 plate with 2 studs](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?P=92593&idColor=85#T=S&C=85&O=%7B%22color%22:85,%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D) in it.

[image]

There are 3 other sets (big enough to have a bag 2 and 3) that have this particular robot police officer head in it, namely:

- [70819 - Bad Cop Car Chase](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=70819-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image]

- [70807 - MetalBeard's Duel](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=70807-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image]

- [70815 - Super Secret Police Dropship](http://alpha.bricklink.com/pages/clone/catalogitem.page?S=70815-1#T=S&O=%7B%22ss%22:%22US%22,%22rpp%22:%22500%22%7D)

[image]

But none of these have the additional pieces as shown in the picture.

Comment: Oh man! Thank you Phil! I believe it has to be the first one with the car chase because there wheels big enough to fit! You have saved my Lego building experience!